# Unlocking laptop appears to open the HUD

Tags: unity, hud, unlock

If I unlock my laptop, I'm forced to manually close the HUD. I've been finding that it's automatically opening with each time I unlock the machine. It's only happening on one of my devices running 13.10 but I can't figure it out. Have I ticked an option I didn't know about? How do I prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

There is [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1227920/comments/29) and this [workaround](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1227920) works fine for me:

```
mjh (moonbug1970) wrote on 2013-10-21:
My workaround was to disable the "Left Alt" shortcut key for the HUD.
```